# Memory allocation and C programming

Tags: memory

I am learning C language and I have a problem to understand the memory allocation and memory address scheme.

- I have a 2 integers the first one have an address 22fd58 and the second one 22fd60. And this is the point when I am getting stucked. One integer is 4Bytes long so if first integer starts on 22fd58 the second one have to start on 22fd5c. If one address holds one byte.

So where is the hole in my logic? And I am working on 64-bit system.

Comment: If you're on a 64-bit system your compiler may actually default `int` to 8 bytes.  And even if not, the compiler may "align" 4-byte quantities on 8-byte boundaries for performance reasons.  The only thing you're guaranteed is that there will be *at least* `sizeof(int)` between the two addresses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heyyy, they are hexadecimal values! :-) Between 0x22fd58 and 0x22fd60 there is a 8 byte difference! :-) Not 2! :-)

From the memory addresses I can see, that you are probably using windows. Visual C on a 64 bit win uses 8 byte-integers, thus all goes as it have to.

Comment: _"Visual C on a 64 bit win uses 8 byte-integers"_ -   It can, but it doesn't have to. An integer won't be 8 bytes in the Windows C environment unless it's explicitly declared to be. int, unsigned int. INT and UINT are 32 bits. So of course are LONG, ULONG, and DWORD. 64-bit Windows uses the LLP  data model, which means that only integers declared as 64 bits (LL, long-long) and pointers are 64 bits. The default integer size remains 32 bits. This answer should not have been accepted.

Comment: @JamieHanrahan I don't have very much experience with 64-bit MSVC, but I remember very clearly that all integers were 64-bit. I.e. `printf("%i\n",sizeof(int));` prints 8 and not 4. In gcc/linux it prints 4, even in 64-bit environment (note, personally I like the MSVC version better). Do you have any reference supporting it? I am ready to update the post.

Comment: I'm sorry but your memory must be mistaken. There's this: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050131-00/?p=36563 I would put Raymond Chen at the same credbility as Mark Russinovich in general developer issues, if not WIndows internals. If that's not sufficient I can provide others, but not in the next few minutes. As someone else mentioned in comments, the behavior observed by the OP may be due to an optimization choice in the compiler. (n.b.: In the above I should have written "LLP64", not just "LLP". Too early in the AM.)

Comment: @JamieHanrahan Ok, I believe you. Considering that the answer is accepted (-> I can't delete it), the question is closed as offtopic, and the OP is disappeared, I suggest to vote the question down and the cleanup script of the SE will delete it soon.

Comment: @JamieHanrahan There is a regularly running task which deletes the downvoted, closed questions. As I know, it runs monthly, weekly or daily.